# Estimator of Bessel function?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, estimators, skellam-distribution

I am trying to estimate the parameters of the modified Bessel function of the first kind for integer order case.

$I_n(wt) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!(m+n)!}(\frac{wt}{2})^{2m+n}$

In Probability form,

$P(t|w,n) = I_n(wt)*other\_terms$

and I would like to estimate the parameters $w$ and $n$, where I got data samples of $t$.

Maximum log-likelihood could be an option but as Bessel function is infinite sum, I'm having a hard time. Does anyone know any related method or paper for this problem?

----- edited

corrected probability form (the original one does not sum to one. my mistake.)

and the Bessel function came up because I am dealing with Skellam distribution.

Comment: *Many* probability distributions have power series expressions like this one. That does not mean they--or Bessel functions--take much time at all to compute accurately. However, you have much more fundamental problems than that. First, $n$ must be an even integer so that its values will be nonnegative.  Worse, the integral of $I_n$ diverges and so cannot be rescaled to form a proper PDF. Could you perhaps edit your question to explain why you think you have data described by a Bessel function?

Comment: The edit helps, but why not just ask a question about the problem you really face rather than trying to abstract out one aspect of it that looks either tangential or irrelevant?  Several threads on our site discuss [computing with the Skellam distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=skellam), so I recommend visiting them first to see whether they offer insight or even solutions to your problem.